# iOS native app working with jquery mobile

Tags: ios, xcode, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

I have my native iOS xcode project that have some views working with jquery mobile and iframes inside it. I am afraid if apple is going to accept it! Could anybody please share his experience on it? Is my app going to be rejected for it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen a post in here of someone complaining because his app was rejected with a mention like :

"this is just an html5 website" or something like that.

Having webviews with html content is not bad in itself but your app must provide some useful stuff, not a "mere" website with 5 page to just look at.